# Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

In iOS, is it possible to put a tap recognizer on a UIWebView, so that when someone single-taps the web view, an action gets performed?

Code below doesn't seem fire handleTap when I tap my webView.

Thanks.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                      action:@selector(handleTap)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[webView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release]; 


-(void) handleTap {
    NSLog(@"tap");
}
```

Answer (score 42):

I found that I had to implement this method to get it to work:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I found that this is not needed when the web view is displaying a PDF document, but it is needed when displaying a text, HTML or image document.

Comment: With the same code. it run for some first time then did not run!

Answer (score 24):

Your UIViewController subclass should implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and return `YES` from `gestureRecognizer: shouldReceiveTouch:` when appropriate.

Then you can assign it to the delegate property of your UIGestureRecognizer.

```
tap.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 10):

1. Add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to view controller

   ```
   <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
   ```
2. Add Tap Gesture to Webview.

   ```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(flip)];
   tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   tap.delegate = self;
   [_webview addGestureRecognizer:tap];
   ```
3. ```
   - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
       return YES;
   }
   ```

Comment: This is the most complete answer. You don’t need tap.numberOfTapsRequired since the default is 1.